# Map.locate() leaflet reload time

Tags: javascript, leaflet

i use leaflet maps to take geolocation of a device. If i use this code my map reload every time that gps send data.. how can i reload map every 60sec for example?

map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 12, maximumAge:50000, watch:true});

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript's setInterval method.

```
setInterval(function() {
  map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 12, maximumAge:50000});
}, 1000 * 60);
```